# See if an app is using the Microphone on Windows 10

Tags: python, c#, windows, powershell, microphone

I'm trying to write a script that let's me check whether the Webcam and Microphone are in use. For the webcam I already managed to write something in Python, however so far I haven't found a good way to do the same for the microphone.

In Windows you have a dedicated setting in the SysTray that is showing up when your microphone is actually used by an app (and even showing which one):
[image: Microphone Setting]
[image: App that is using Microphone]

So obviously Windows knows whether it's used at the moment (that's all I would need) and even which application is using it. However I did not find any way to read that information out in any way yet.

Is it possible to somehow get the data from Windows itself?
At this point, I don't even mind which language would be used for it, Python, C#, PowerShell or whatever.

PS: I know there might be ways to access the microphone wihtout it being shown in the SysTray, but this case is not relevant for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not a "proper" one, I just used the image recognition approach described below, that worked just fine for me but it's probably not ideal for any kind of "production" environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed it now with the following approach - I'm just taking a screenshot of the desktop and check for the icon I expect to appear in the SysTray in case some app is using the microphone.

For this I used the package *imagesearch* that can be installed via pip:
*pip3 install python-imageseach-drov0*

Then I take a screenshot via that package and check whether the item is visible on the screen:

```
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import imagesearch

pos = imagesearch(imagePath)
microphone_on = pos[0] != -1
if microphone_on:
    print("Microphone is in use")
else:
    print("Microphone is not in use")
```

The image defined in *imagePath* looks like this:
[image: Microphone Icon]

I found infos for the package on following page: https://brokencode.io/how-to-easily-image-search-with-python/

The recognition works very well and fast, but of course this might not be the best solution and works for simple cases where you just want to know whether anything is using the mic or not. It still would be better if there is some API available that could be asked, but it's better than nothing and solves my problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would your Python script report while this proposed answer is displayed in your favorite browser?

Comment: Hi, as long as the taskbar with the systray is visible, it works fine. If you run anything in fullscreen (e.g. games or something in presentation mode) of course it won't detect it (unless you have a second screen with the taskbar). Does this answer your question or did I get it wrong? :-)

Comment: The code appears to be looking for image data only. Since the image you are searching for appears on this answer, your implementation would report a hit as long as it is on screen. Even when the microphone isn't in use. If that is the indeed the case, what you have is a brittle solution, with the opportunity to produce both false positives as well as false negatives. While spending boatloads of compute power. Have a look into the [Windows.Media.Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices) namespace and see if you can use any of those interfaces instead.

Comment: Ah ok now I get it. Yes this would detect it as "Microphone is in use". However the imagesearch would allow to narrow the position (e.g. for the taskbar). It is also very unlikely to encounter this image "in the wild" just like this, so it's still works fine for my use case which is a personal project that runs this check just every 2 minutes or so.

I checked out the namespace you mentioned before, but couldn't find anything there.

I agree though that this is not the solution for a professional application as it's not reliable enough

Comment: In that case, [Audio Session Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-session-events) might be what you're looking for. [Audio Events for Legacy Audio Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-events-for-legacy-audio-applications) shows a small sample that registers for notifications, to illustrate the core principles.

Comment: Check app using Microphone on Windows.  Wow is searching Images on Linux an acceptable answer?